# npm install failing socket.io windows 8

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I have searched all over and have not found a solution to this problem.

I am attempting to install socket.io using npm. I have python 2.7.3 installed and MSVS 2013 express which I know are the dependencies for node-gyp. I always get this message and have gotten it while trying to install other packages.

```
C:\Sites\node_chat>npm install socket.io


> ws@0.4.31 install
C:\Sites\node_chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Sites\node_chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild/


> ws@0.5.0 install C:\Sites\node_chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Sites\node_chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
socket.io@1.3.4 node_modules\socket.io
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
├── socket.io-parser@2.2.3 (isarray@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, component-emitter@1.1.2, benchmark@1.0.0, json3@3.2.6)
├── socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2, socket.io-parser@2.2.2)
├── engine.io@1.5.1 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.2.1, ws@0.5.0)
└── socket.io-client@1.3.4 (indexof@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, to-array@0.1.3, component-bind@1.0.0, backo2@1.0.2, object-component@0.0.3, component-emitter@1.1.2, has-binary@0.1.6, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.5.1)
```

I am running node v0.10.35 and npm v1.4.28 by the way. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see an error in your listing, does it not work, or are you simply concerned that it seems to always compile when you do the install?

Comment: When I try using it, it fails. You can find my code and error message [here](http://pastebin.com/80PfBmxt). I do not know what is not working

Comment: The error is 'address in use' which probably doesn't have anything to do with a bad install. Do you have another server running on port 8080? Change the port and see if you stil get it.

Comment: Wow. Changed the port and sure enough it worked. I guess something else is running on 8080. Thank you